# Show that $\sup f_n = \sup g_n$ almost everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that we have a sequence of (Lebesuge) measurable functions $f_n,g_n$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose also that for each $n$, $f_n=g_n$ almost everywhere.

I want to prove that $\sup f_n=\sup g_n$ almost everywhere, given above conditions. That is to say, I need to show that the set of points $x$ for which the two sequences $f_n(x)$, $g_n(x)$ have different supremum is null.

However I only have very vague ideas about this problem: I tried to find a set which contains the set $\{ \sup f_n\neq \sup g_n\}$ which we can easily identify as a null set, and then by completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ (as a measure space) we are done.

But I always get stuck at some point due to lack of further ideas/ or maybe because my approach wasn't a correct one.

Any helps appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $E_n = \{x: f_n(x)\neq g_n(x) \}$, so $E_n$ is a null set for all $n$.

Let $E = \bigcup_n E_n$, so $E$ is also a null set (since countable unions of null sets are null sets).

Define $f=\sup_nf_n$ and $g=\sup_n g_n$. Then $f(x)=g(x)$ if $x \notin E$ (because $f_n(x)=g_n(x)$ for all $n$ if $x \notin E$), so it follows that $\{ x: f(x) \neq g(x) \} \subset E$. Since subsets of null sets are null sets, it follows that $\{ x: f(x) \neq g(x) \}$ is a null set, which is the desired result.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was kind of thing I was trying to figure out but I couldn't lay them out clearly and confused myself

Comment: Yeah sure :)  It's a pretty common notion in measure theory to break apart sets as countable unions of simpler things and then proceed from there.